# Variable de entorno en propiedades gradle

Tags: android, gradle

Estoy configurando un plugin android para automatizar la subida del apk a producción desde el propio android studio.

En un ejemplo que sigo aparece lo siguiente (gradle.properties):

```
AppKeystoreReleaseLocation = keystore/release.keystore
AppReleaseKeyAlias = UNDEFINED
AppReleaseStorePassword = UNDEFINED
AppReleaseKeyPassword = UNDEFINED
```

Y en el build.gradle:

```
signingConfigs {
    // You must set up an environment var before release signing
    // Run: export APP_KEY={password}
    release {
        storeFile file("${AppKeystoreReleaseLocation}")
        keyAlias "${AppReleaseKeyAlias}"
        storePassword "${AppReleaseStorePassword}"
        keyPassword "${AppReleaseKeyPassword}"
    }
}
```

Simplemente debo escribir `export AppReleaseKeyPassword=mypassword` en la consola y lo cogerá automáticamente?

Comment: Hola , no entiendo esta parte: "escribir export AppReleaseKeyPassword=mypassword en la consola y lo cogerá automáticamente?", te refieres a que tomará el password o la generación del .apk

Comment: Hola, yo lo que no entiendo es el comentario : "Run: export APP_KEY={password}"